# Gradient of a function involving maxima

Tags: derivatives, optimization, vector-analysis

How do I find the gradient of a function like $f(\vec{v})$ where
$$ f(\vec{v}) = \max_{\vec{t}\geq 0} g(\vec{v},\vec{t})$$

For example, I have a function defined as follows:

\begin{align} f(\vec{v}) = \max_{\vec{t} \geq 0} \left(  \gamma v_1 \frac{\lambda_A\cdot(1-\exp(-\lambda_At_0))}{\lambda_A + \lambda_B+\lambda_C+\lambda_D} 
+ \gamma v_2 \frac{\lambda_B\cdot(1-\exp(-\lambda_Bt_1))}{\lambda_A + \lambda_B+\lambda_C+\lambda_D} \\
+ (c\cdot(1-\exp(-\lambda_Ct_0)) + \gamma v_0) \frac{\lambda_C}{\lambda_A + \lambda_B+\lambda_C+\lambda_D} \\
(c\cdot(1-\exp(-\lambda_Dt_1)) + \gamma v_0) \frac{\lambda_D}{\lambda_A + \lambda_B+\lambda_C+\lambda_D}\right)
\end{align}
where all $\lambda$ and are positive constants, $c$ is a negative constant, $\gamma \in [0,1]$, and $\exp$ is the exponential function.

I've noticed that this function is linear with respect to $v$, but I'm not entirely sure what to do with that.